# Custom wp_list_tables redirect on specfic page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

I have created a custom plugin and added the wp_list_tables and added some bulk actions, What I want to achieve when user select fields it should go on another page where, I can get all selected id's.
Currently it's going in process_bulk_action and from there I am redirecting on anther page using get method is there any way to redirect all data using post method or direct submit on that page?

```
 public function process_bulk_action() {
...........
            $url = admin_url('admin.php?page=youthclub'); 
             if('bulk-sms' === $this->current_action() && isset($_POST['bulk-delete']) ) {
                $export_ids = implode('-',esc_sql( $_POST['bulk-delete'] ));
                $url_3= admin_url('admin.php?page=send-bulk-sms&ids='.$export_ids); 
                self::redirect($url_3);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @sandrodz it's working but I don't want 2 step to reach that page also don't want to send value in url